# Error: InvalidPipeArgument

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, ag-grid

I am receiving the above error when trying to load the data using API call.

```
      ngOnInit(http1: Http) {

    this.rowData = http1.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/15psn9');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Http` returns `Observable`. So you need to change your code as below.

```
ngOnInit(http1: Http) {
  http1.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/15psn9')
     .subscribe(data => this.rowData = data);
}
```